# Spivak's 'Calculus', 5-23(a$\land$b). How does $\frac{l}{\infty}=0$ make sense?

Tags: limits, infinity

**Problem**

> (a) $\;\;\;$ Suppose that $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)$ exists and is $\neq 0$. Prove that if $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)$ does not exist, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)g(x)$ also does not exist.
>
> (b) $\;\;\;$ Prove the same result if $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}|f(x)|=\infty$.

**Solutions from answer book**

> (a) $\;\;\;$ If $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)g(x)$ existed, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)}$ would also exist.
>
> (b) $\;\;\;$ Cleary, if $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)g(x)$ existed, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)=0$.

---

Solution (a) is clear. Is there a more mathematical way of stating solution (b)?

The way I sort of make sense of solution (b) is through solution (a) since, if $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)g(x)=l$ existed, then
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)g(x)\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{f(x)}=l\cdot\frac{1}{\infty}=\frac{l}{\infty}=0$$
But since $\infty$ is not a number, how does this make sense? (it makes intuitive sense of course, but I want the maths behind the intuition).

Comment: $\frac{1}{\infty}$ gets closer to $0$ as the denominator approaches $\infty$ so they just say its zero

Comment: As you have confirmed that $\infty$ is not a number, you better say what it is... What is it?

Comment: Let $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=\infty$ mean that, $\forall N$, $\exists \delta$ s.t., $\forall x$, if $0<|x-a|<\delta\
\Rightarrow f(x)>N$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take the definitions:

If $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = C$ then for all $x \in (-\delta, \delta)$ we have $f(x) \in (C - 1, C + 1)$. Thus $|f(x)| < |C| + 1$.

If $\lim_{x \to 0} |g(x)| = \infty$ then for all $x \in (-\delta',\delta')$ we have $|g(x)| > M$.

Replacing $\delta$ with $\min\{\delta,\delta'\}$ we therefore have

$$ \frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|} < \frac{|f(x)|}{M} < \frac{|C|+1}{M}$$

Now choose $M$ appropriately and shrink $\delta$ accordingly, you can make this sum smaller than $\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$.